# Overriding a .xml from an External Library

Tags: android

i have imported a external lib using Gradle , i need to change a color and a image link, which are written in an .xml file inside of the ext Lib drawable folder. I cannot make direct changes to this build files. How do i override this resources?

`

```
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#FFC6292D" />

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

`

Comment: what is the xml you posted? i assume it is a part of a larger xml? if so, post it

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFC6292D" />

            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list><!-- From: file:/Users/thomasdao/Documents/workspace/Caldroid/caldroid/src/main/res/drawable/red_border.xml -->`

Comment: then read `android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable` documentation on how to get a particular layer (<item>) of your <layer-list>, when you have it cast it to `GradientDrawable` and change the properties you want